# cc1.exe: fatal error: begginer.c: Permission denied compilation terminated

Tags: c

I deleted my antivirus software because the terminal from visual studio code kept saying

```
permission was denied
```

Now I'm getting this error, I'm running a C file with Visual Studio Code.

Can someone help me, please?

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\wanofficial\Downloads\DOMCart (1)\DOMCart\" &&
gcc begginer.c -o begginer && "c:\Users\wanofficial\Downloads\DOMCart (1)\DOMCart\"begginer cc1.exe: fatal error: begginer.c: Permission denied compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Maybe you are compiling while the previous compiled binary is being executed?

Comment: `-o beginner` generates this error if you have a subdirectory named beginner, can't overwrite a directory with a file.  `-o beginner.o` would fix it.

Comment: Permission problem is not likely related to antivirus, but why are you building in your downloads directory?

Comment: I'm trying to find the right path to download in im using visual studio code. Any recommendations for the right path to save the file?

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused because the executable process is already running. You can't overwrite a file that's in use. Or do you have permission to write the destination file in that directory?